# Invert colors of a video using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

Is it possible to invert colors of a video using FFMPEG?

It seemed to me from [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/928151/ffmpeg-eq-filter-complex-contrast) that it might be possible but I can't figure out the correct filter.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The lut filter family has a bespoke mode for doing this, when you don't know whether the input is YUV or RGB.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -vf negate output.mov
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `lutrgb` or `lutyuv` video filter:

```
ffmpeg -i input_file -vf lutrgb="r=negval:g=negval:b=negval" output_file
```

or:

```
ffmpeg -i input_file -vf lutyuv="y=negval:u=negval:v=negval" output_file
```

Source: [FFmpeg Filters Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html)

Answer (score 0):

This also work for inverting alpha channel in videos

```
ffmpeg -i input_file -vf lutrgb="a=negval" output_file
```